# .net core 5 with EF LINQ (NPGSQL) Timestamp parameter in a function causing an Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005)

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Try to call a function with a timestamp parameter (tried with and without time zone) and I get this error.

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 22007: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "@p1"
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Rainman.Data.Repositories.RoutePlanRepository.GetCustomerRoutingCacheAsync(Int64 id) in C:\Users\sam_w\source\repos\rainman_api\lib\rainmanLibrary\Rainman.Data\Repositories\RoutePlanRepository.cs:line 893
   at Rainman.Services.RoutePlanService.GetCustomerRoutingCaches(Int64 id) in C:\Users\sam_w\source\repos\rainman_api\lib\rainmanLibrary\Rainman.Services\RoutePlanService.cs:line 184
   at Rainman.Api.Controllers.RoutePlanController.GetCustomerRoutingCache(Int64 id) in C:\Users\sam_w\source\repos\rainman_api\Rainman.Api\Controllers\RoutePlanController.cs:line 137
   at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 22007
    MessageText: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "@p1"
    Position: 51
    File: datetime.c
    Line: 3761
    Routine: DateTimeParseError
```

This the code that is erring:

```
        FormattableString query = $"SELECT public.fn_test_lcr_custom('{routePlan.DeckApplyCustomer.tg_id}', timestamp '{routePlan.effective_date.ToString("u")}');";
        Console.WriteLine($"\n\nQUERY:\n{query}\n\n");
        List<CustomerRoutingCache> tmpList = await RainmanDbContext.CustomerRoutingCaches.FromSqlInterpolated(query).ToListAsync();
```

I have tried several different string format and can get nothing to work.  I even have an example of getting timestamp to working with a the same format.

```
            string query = $"SELECT fnlcr_custom('{tg.tg_id}', timestamp '{asOfTS.ToString("u")}');";
            return await RainmanDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(query);
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

**BTW using**

.net core 5

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v5.0.8

NPgSQL v5.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should remove single quotes and `timestamp` from the query text and use `FromSqlInterpolated`. It will bind a parameter with the appropriate type (the mappings can be seen in [.NET types and PostgreSQL types](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html#:%7E:text=NET%20type%20usually%20have%20a%20higher%20resolution%20but,%20%20N%2FA%20%202%20more%20rows%20) section of the Npgsql documentaion) for each token inside the interpolated string, e.g.

```cs
var query = db.Set<CustomerRoutingCache>().FromSqlInterpolated(
    $"select * from public.fn_test_lcr_custom({routePlan.DeckApplyCustomer.tg_id}, {routePlan.effective_date})"
);

Console.WriteLine(query.ToQueryString());

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Ivan being you was so helpful with the previous question.  This same code know gives a different error.  fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Rainman.Data.RainmanDbContext'.
      System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
       ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream
       ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during reading attempt
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.

Comment: @SamWare This is virtually impossible, since it requires having access to the actual function and data (even fake, but reproducing the issue), which apparently I don't have. Try executing the function with the same parameters using some native tool (or plain ADO.NET), doesn't sound to be EF Core related, but one never know.